# Looking for a third party iOS (or Android) app compatible with CarPlay (or Android Auto) that can display GIS shapes

Tags: android, ios, gis

I was looking forward to loading Google My Maps on CarPlay to be able to show selected kml files (selected parcels in this case) on my car’s screen. I was disappointed to find out “My Maps” on Google Maps for CarPlay is not supported at the moment.

Now that Apple has opened up CarPlay to other navigation apps, has anyone found a way to display GIS data on their CarPlay screen?

I also have an old Android phone and would be willing to just break it out to use for the purpose if there is an android solution out there compatible with Android Auto.

Also, if somebody has at least 300 reputation points on this forum please add the tags “CarPlay” and “android-auto” to this question if you don’t mind